# Selenium : Unable to mouseover an element

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to access a element which is in page DOM. I am able to fetch the element and print it but no able to click it. The main reason is because there is a page toggle which comes out once you hover over and will retrieve when you move the mouse pointer away from it. There is a button at the top of the toggle which I am unable to click because of this toggle function. I tried mouse over, explicit wait and all the other thing but unable to click the button. When I tried to print the page source I can see all the elements, but for some reason it is not visible to selenium.

Button to click:

attribute name : data-aid="sb-toggle"

`self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[data-aid="sb-toggle"]').click()`

Also tried this:

page-sidebar is  tag which is the visible toggle in the page.

`sideBar = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('page-sidebar')
toggleButton = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[data-aid="sb-toggle"]')
hover = ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(sideBar).move_to_element(toggleButton)
        hover.click().build().perform()`

> MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: Offset within element cannot be scrolled into view: (140, 288): [object HTMLDivElement]

I am not getting the element not found exception because the element is found in the page source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hover = ActionChains(self.driver).move_by_offset(1,1)
    hover.click(self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[data-aid="sb-toggle"]')).perform()
```

the offset(1,1) if the top left corner of the page where I hover to and then click on the button.